# EventAggregator, is it thread-safe?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism, eventaggregator

Is this thread-safe?

The EventAggregator in Prism is a very simple class with only one method. I was surprised when I noticed that there was no lock around the null check and creation of a new type to add to the private _events collection. If two threads called GetEvent simultaneously for the same type (before it exists in _events) it looks like this would result in two entries in the collection.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the single instance of the event managed by this EventAggregator. Multiple calls to this method with the same <typeparamref name="TEventType"/> returns the same event instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEventType">The type of event to get. This must inherit from <see cref="EventBase"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>A singleton instance of an event object of type <typeparamref name="TEventType"/>.</returns>
    public TEventType GetEvent<TEventType>() where TEventType : EventBase
    {
        TEventType eventInstance = _events.FirstOrDefault(evt => evt.GetType() == typeof(TEventType)) as TEventType;
        if (eventInstance == null)
        {
            eventInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TEventType>();
            _events.Add(eventInstance);
        }
        return eventInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not thread safe.

1. The **instance member access** of the List class itself are **NOT thread safe**, as per [MSDN under Thread safety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
2. The **method itself** is not thread safe

   1. 2 threads could enter the method at the same time
   2. Both try to get the FirstOrDefault
   3. Both get nothing
   4. Both add a new TEventType

I would

1. switch to one of the System.CollectionConcurrentX collections in .NET 4
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx
   or
2. do your own locking

Comment: +1 @Peter Agreed. I came here to sanity check after having some issues and then looking at the code for EventAggregator in reflector. I cannot believe that they did not make it thread-safe given the intended architectural use. I was surprised anyway.

Comment: @chibacity me too, surprised I was ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what "_events" is...

There are some awesome new thread-safe classes in .NET 4 ...
Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: sorry, I should have included it. It's just a list :

private readonly List<EventBase> _events = new List<EventBase>();

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on that code paste, I'd say no, it's not 100% thread safe.

Of course, you have the source, so you can just add the lock yourself. :)

Actually, as a general rule of thumb, I include the entire CAL project in my solution, at least at the start. It helps a lot in debugging those odd region registration/creation exceptions...